# Form post replaces " (double quotes) with &quot;

Tags: php, html, forms

I have developed on a local server. When I upload the pages to the website then I get this problem. It does not occur on my local server (WAMP).

```
 <form  class='form-horizontal' method='post' id='uparticle'>

...

<textarea class='form-control <?php echo $cked ?>' name='editor1' id='editor1' rows='10' cols='80'>
      <?php echo $article; ?>
      </textarea>
```

When I submit the form it replaces `"` with `\&quot;`. I have used ckeditor but it is not that, as I have also sent the $article in a textdata field without using ckeditor.

I have also eliminated the database write by displaying the textdata before it is written to the database.

For example:
`<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">` gets rewritten as `<table border="\&quot;1\&quot;" cellpadding="\&quot;2\&quot;" cellspacing="\&quot;0\&quot;">`

I think it is probably some configuration setting, but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: What is the version of PHP on local and live environment?

Comment: If you have a really old server you might have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled (which could explain an ampersand before a quote) but I can't think of any function or setting that will create HTML entities automatically. This feels more like a JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may probably be caused by `magic_quotes_gpc` setting if you're using an old PHP version (i.e., 5.3). Check the settings in your php.ini and set its value to "0". Check other magic_quotes settings as well, you may turn them off also.

For more information please look http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: @BlooMort Glad to be helpful

Comment: This can't be the answer (it doesn't explain the `&quot;` HTML entities) unless the OP is omitting something.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, this effect is a collision of client-side scripting and server-side magic quotes. But when he turned magic quotes off, the collision is gone, why it can't be an accetpable answer? It's not a rare case, if you google for it, i.e. https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=766517

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **htmlspecialchars_decode** which convert special HTML entities back to characters

For Example:

```
<?php
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
<p>this -> "</p>
<p>this -> &quot;</p>
```

And use this `meta` tag in you HTML code:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`